# Stream different ssh servers using nginx

Tags: mongodb, docker, nginx, ssh

## My Environment

- I have 5 different mongodb containers, each has its own ssh server.
- I have nginx container connected with all mongodb containers. I can reach the 22 ports like  this: `mongodb-server-1:22`

## My goal

Normally, I have to create a port for each ssh server in order to reach them. (e.g. 2220, 2221, 2222) I do not want to do this because I think that this is not good way to do. More the servers grow, more the ports needed.

I want to publish just a single port (e.g. 2323) and I want to proxy all of my ssh servers like this:

> **ssh1.srv.domain.com → mongodb-server-1:22**

> **ssh2.srv.domain.com → mongodb-server-2:22**

> **ssh3.srv.domain.com → mongodb-server-3:22**

With this way, I should be able to connect to my mongodb servers using these configurations from MongoDBCompass with my credentials (username and identity file):

SSH Hostname: **ssh1.srv.domain.com**

SSH Port: 2323

## Nginx Informations

I use nginx version 1.25.0

```
nginx version: nginx/1.25.0
built by gcc 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
```

### Attempt 1:

I can connect to my mongodb server with ip address and port (2323) using this configuration without any problem, but as I mentioned before, I want to use domain names like **ssh1.srv.domain.com**

```
stream {
  server {
      listen 2323;
      proxy_pass mongodb-server-1:22;
  }
}
```

### Attempt 2:

I tried to connect with ip address **ssh1.srv.domain.com** and port **2323** but MongoDBCompass says that **Connection lost before handshake**.

Also I want to mention that, I have a valid ssl certificate for `*.srv.domain.com` thanks to certbot, and I have a **CNAME** record for `*.srv` on cloudflare.

```
stream {
  map $ssl_preread_server_name $upstream {
      ssh1.srv.domain.com mongodb-server-1:22;
  }

  server {
      listen 2323;
      proxy_pass $upstream;
      ssl_preread on;
  }
}
```

### Attempt 3:

I tried to add ssl certificates but still, it did not work.

```
stream {
  map $ssl_preread_server_name $upstream {
      ssh1.srv.domain.com mongodb-server-1:22;
  }

  server {
      listen 2323 ssl;

      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/com/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/com/domain.com/privkey.pem;

      proxy_pass $upstream;
      ssl_preread on;
  }
}
```

I want to mention that ssl certificates are valid, and the path is correct. I also tried to connect from cli via `ssh` command like this:

```
ssh -p 2323 -i ~/.ssh/private_key root@ssh1.srv.domain.com
```

and I got this error:

```
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by <REMOTE_HOST_IP> port 2323
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to have access to multiple ssh servers on a single port on the same host (via docker)?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to do. I can access them from different ports, there is no problem, but I want to access them using my domain `domain.com`. I want to put `ssh1.srv.domain.com` as ip address on MongoDBCompass. Since I created a CNAME record, it will point to my main machine.

Comment: You may need to deploy an overlay network and then isolate each container ssh port from the host... if you do a port mapping to the host then it will not work AFAIK

Comment: I already did not expose any ports like 22 on containers. The nginx container and other mongob containers are connected each other with a network called `nginx-network` so I can reach them by `container-name:container-port` (e.g. `mongodb-server-1:22`) The problem at nginx side. I want to redirect stream by incoming address such as `ssh1.srv.domain.com`.